# What's the difference between the two maven modules in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I noticed that since Kafka 0.8.2.0, Kafka has shipped with a new maven module:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But, it still ships with the older maven module

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What's the difference or relationship between these two modules? I noticed that SimpleConsumer that I have used before is in `kafka_2.11` module,but not in `kafka-clients`, does it mean that if I want to use SimpleConsumer, I still have to include the kafka_2.11 module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between kafka and kafka-clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074281/what-is-the-difference-between-kafka-and-kafka-clients)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleConsumer` was an old implementation of Consumer in the Kafka. It's now deprecated in favor of new Consumer API. In Kafka 0.8.1, team [had started](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/) to re-implement Producer/Consumer APIs, and it went into `kafka-client` maven artifact. You can trace the changes between versions: [0.8.1](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/0.8.1/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients), [0.9.0](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/0.9.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients), [1.0.0](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients), ...

You need to use new Consumer API if you're using Kafka >= 0.10.

Comment: Thanks @alex-ott for the help answer.